# R Leaflet: lines missing when plotting polylines

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a pretty simple spatial object composed of a bunch of lines. I can plot it in different ways with no problems: QGIS, mapshaper.org. Even the standard R `plot()` function:

[image: This plot is OK]

But when I plot it with `leaflet()`, some segments mysteriously disappear, leaving disconnected lines behind:

[image]

A reproducible example follows. NOTE: I use a GeoJSON source file for simplicity here. I have also tried saving the lines as an ESRI shapefile, with the same effect: The data is plotted OK with QGIS, or `plot()`, etc but not with `leaflet()`.

```
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/nij2oa2rp7ijaaj/commuter_rail.geojson?dl=1",
                           method = "auto", mode = "wb", destfile = "commuter_rail.json")
commuterLines <- readOGR("commuter_rail.json",
                         "OGRGeoJSON")

# Straight R Plot - Looks good
plot(commuterLines)

# Plot using leaflet - Some lines are missing!

leaflet() %>% addPolylines(data = commuterLines)
```

UPDATE:

Here's the reproducible example running as a shiny app, hosted at shinyapps.io, and showing the weird leaflet behavior: https://havb.shinyapps.io/leaflet_example/

Comment: the download of the json doesnt work for me. Have you tried `readLines("foo.json")` ? https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/json.html

Comment: @maRtin, oops, fixed now.  Reading the json is not the issue, I get the exact same (weird) result if I read the data in ESRI shapefile format. I just used a json file in the example for convenience. If it's useful, here's the same data as a shapefile: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yq7vh4w43q3suy/MBTA.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** the problem seems to be a bug in an older version of the leaflet package available from CRAN. Installing the latest development version from Github resolves the issue.

I don't have enough rep to comment, but I tried your code and it worked for me:

[image]

Perhaps it has something to do with your local configuration? Have you tried reinstalling the leaflet package?

Comment: This is really weird. I reinstalled leaflet, and updated R and every package, just in case. I still get the broken map with leaflet. I even uploaded the code to shinyapps, and... same (bad) result! See [here](https://havb.shinyapps.io/leaflet_example/)

Comment: I tried to replicate the error again, and it still worked for me. Do you know which geometries from the json file are not showing up? Perhaps there's an error in those lines of the json file? I am happy to send you the output of my  `communterLines` SpatialLinesDataFrame as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no error in the `json` file, for two reasons: I get the exact same error when plotting the data as an `ESRI shapefile` ; and I can plot the `json` file just fine using `QGIS` or `CARTO`. `leaflet` is the only constant for the wrong plot. In fact, I found he problem while using a `shapefile`. I just converted the data to `json` because it also triggers the error and was easier to share. Maybe we are using different `leaflet` versions? Mine is 1.0.1. And I'll gladly take your spatial dataframe!

Comment: I am using leaflet version 1.0.2.9008.

Comment: Bingo! The latest CRAN leaflet version seems to have a bug that springs with this particular spatial object. Installing the latest development version from Github solved the issue. If you rewrite/update your answer to indicate this I'll accept it